# ARRAYFORMULA, чтобы сделать ссылки

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Имею вот такую формулу. В столбце "C" начиная со второй строки идут телефонные номера.
И все бы хорошо, но после того как строки с данными кончаются, начало ссылки https//wa.me/ продолжает вставляться до бесконечности. Как правильно написать? Так как количество строк может быть разное, конец строки обозначить не предлагать :))

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(CONCAT("https://wa.me/";C2:C);C2:C))
```

Такой вариант не работает:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(CONCAT("https://wa.me/",C2:C(COUNTIF(A:A, "<>")),C2:C(COUNTIF(A:A, "<>")))))
```

Comment: Что-то не пойму, когда пытаюсь засунуть в CONCAT еще куски URL, гугл ругается что аргументов должно быть 2 и не больше. Хотя в примерах функции CONCAT аргументов сколько угодно может быть.

Comment: Без примера трудно что-то сказать дельное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, конкатенация через амперсанд `&` для `ARRAYFORMULA` более частоупотребляемая операция, т.к. для множественного аргумента для соединения строк требуется `CONCATENATE`, а не `CONCAT`.

В общей сложности

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(C2:C<>"";HYPERLINK("https://wa.me/" & C2:C & "/";C2:C);"")
)
```

должно вывести то, что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось :) Я думал что CONCAT и CONCATENATE - это одна и та же функция